# Git Auto pull from Azure Repos and run on VM

Tags: git, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I am not very good at Git, I have a project to run same python code located in AzureDevops Repos on multiple VMs.
How can I create a .bat file that pulls code from AzureDevops Repo and run on VM? I need it because in case there are some changes needed to be applied on the code, I will not need to go to each VM to change and save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use .bat file to pulls code from AzureDevops Repo and run on VM through command, please see whether the following steps help:

1.Click the 'copy' icon to get the URL.
[image]

2.Go to the folder that you would like to save the .bat file and the git file. Create a .txt file and write 'git clone URL' in it, save and close, modify the file name as ***.bat.
[image]

Create a .txt file and write the added content(here I use it as example, you could add wanted command here), then do 'git add .''git commit -m""'and 'git push'.save and close, modify the file name as *****.bat.

```
cd a1p
echo hello world(echo to add content) >> README.md (the modified file name)
echo How are you? >> README.md
type README.md
git add .
git commit -m"goodcommit1"(name your commit)
git push
```

3.Double click ***.bat first and after it finishes, click *****.bat file.
you will get things like this when double click the ***.bat file:

[image]

It will automatically close when finishing the clone. And here you could see the folder named a1p in the target folder.
Then double click *****.bat file, after it finish, you will see these like this in the README file:

[image]

Push the changes to your repo then you could pull it to other VMs with the changes. Hope it could do some help.